# How to change the symbol of time signature in Lilypond

Tags: time-signatures, lilypond

Instead of the big C or numerical time signature, I must use the symbol "サ". This time signature "サ" is common in many Chinese music pieces, it means "freely". How do I achieve this with Lilypond? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If that sign means freely, and doesn't really refer to bars specifically like a standard time signature does, why put anything in there anyway?

Comment: @Tim it's just an established notating method in many east Asia pieces. Many traditional east Asian piece have very different rhythmic than traditional western music. Specific to the piece I am engraving, only the first section is "freely", after that the western rhythmic kicks in. Somewhere in the middle it's "freely" again, so I will need this symbol to mark exactly where the rhythmic should be freely.....

Comment: Huh, so the Chinese borrowed that symbol from the Japanese? It looks an awful lot like katakana to me....

Comment: @Dekkakeci it's actually another way around....the Japanese borrowed symbols from Chinese, and then simplified them.

Comment: @NicoleNaumann - Now I recall reading that katakana is made of simplified kanji portions. However, I find it suspicious that the time signature symbol looks just like katakana, to the point that I still find it easier to believe that the Chinese borrowed that symbol back from the Japanese.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lilypond has the great ability to make anything look like anything. Really, *any* object has a property `stencil`, which tells Lilypond how the object should be rendered, and it can be overridden by whatever you want. If you override it with `#ly:text-interface::print`, you can then specify any markup in a property called `text`.

In your case, I would use any time signature (doesn't matter which one since it is being replaced with the character), override its stencil and immediately switch to a cadenza mode, like this:

```
\once\override Staff.TimeSignature.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
\once\override Staff.TimeSignature.text = \markup{\fontsize #8 "サ" }
\once\override Staff.TimeSignature.extra-offset = #'(0 . -2)
\time 4/4
\cadenzaOn

% Your music goes here.
```

**Edit**: Apparently you can drop the `\time 4/4` and it will still work okay. Thanks to @timbo.

I needed to make the Chinese character a lot bigger with `\fontsize`, and then shift it vertically by setting the `extra-offset` property, so that it is nicely centered. By the way, the cadenza mode is a bit of pain to use: each barline must be given with `\bar "|"`, linebreaks can occur only at "invisible bars" made with  `\bar ""`, accidentals are remembered forever and the beaming is switched off, so you must specify all the beams manually with `[` and `]`.

Then you could get something like this:
[image]

Here is a [lilybin](http://lilybin.com/p78uh0/1) for you (it's a web app where you can write Lilypond snippets and they are compiled into PDF which is immediately rendered). However, they apparently don't have proper Chinese fonts installed, so I had to use the letter "A" instead.

Comment: Can the explicit `\time 4/4` be dropped as that is the default?

Comment: @timbo, it turns out it can. I didn't actually think it would work.

Comment: Thank you so much Ramillies, you saved my day!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can make the time signature transparent with `\override Staff.TimeSignature.transparent = ##t`

e.g.

```
\version "2.20"

\header {
  title =   "Transparent Key Signature"
}

righthand =  {
  \key c \major
  \override Staff.TimeSignature.transparent = ##t
  \clef "treble"
  \relative c'' {
  c2-1 d e1 f2 e d r \bar "|."
  }
}

\score {
    \context Staff = "one" <<
      \righthand
    >>
  \layout { }
}
```

[image]

However the time signature is a pretty important aspect that will dictate how bars are structured (and defaults to 4/4 as still seen in the example)

You probably want to read the section on [Unmetered music](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/displaying-rhythms#unmetered-music) sometimes also referred to as `free time`

As for adding the character サ, that looks like the Japanese katakana 'sa' rather than a Chinese character. And サ is phonetic, it has no inherent meaning. You may want to doublecheck your source.

Defering to [ramillies](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/32425/ramillies) answer as he's listing better overrides